# Table binding and when when using htmlspecialchars - JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm using fat-free framework. In controller I return json data.

I'm using `htmlspecialchars` - I need to show html and css .

```
$results = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $results[$counter]['id'] = $row['id'];
  $results[$counter]['number'] = $row['number'];
  $results[$counter]['text'] = htmlspecialchars($row['text']);
  $counter++;
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

In my view I have:

```
function onCommand(sender, command, fArgs) {

  obj = FunctionArgsToJsonObject(fArgs);

  if (sender == "tbl_data" ) {
    switch (command) {
      case "edit_text": {

        CallAPI("GET", "text/" + obj.id, function (data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);

          BindForm(data, "info");

          $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <table id="tbl_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th binding="id" action="">ID</th>
            <th binding="number" action="">№</th>
            <th binding="text" action="">Text</th>
            <th command="edit_text" buttonStyle="warning" buttontitle="edit"  icon="edit" >Edit</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


<!--Modal for edit -->
<div class="row col-md-12" style="width:1000px !important;">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
            <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="info">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2" for="form-field-1">№ </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input id="frm_number" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2" for="form-field-1">Text</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <textarea id="frm_text" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When for example my text in column text is:

```
<a href='register.php' style='font-size:16px;'>Register</a>
```

There is error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 77 of the JSON data
```

How to fix that?

Thank you in advance!

**Edited:**  I tried this:

`$results[$counter]['text'] = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($row['text']));`

and it;s working but only for single quotes.

How to escape double quotes, too?

Comment: what is in the $row['text']?

Comment: Some strings from database that contain html and css and I'm using htmlspecialchars to show them.

Comment: test case <a href='test' style='color:red;'>Test</a>, htmlspecialchars works for this string.

Comment: Yes, it works but it doesn't work for double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question and it is:

In controller I'm using the following:

```
$results[$counter]['text'] = htmlentities($row['text'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

I escape it in view in js:

```
CallAPI("GET", "text/", function (data) {
    data = data.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    BindTable($("#tbl_data"), data, "", null, { hasSearchPaging: true,  hasSorting: true });
});
```

Comment: The JSON specification only allows for double quoted strings here you can find some useful info http://stackoverflow.com/users/2009750/%C9%A2%CA%9C%CA%98%CA%82%CA%88-%CA%80%C9%9B%C9%94%CA%98%C9%B4

Comment: I think it's working for both single and double quotes.